# How Could I Store A Struct In Char A Byte Array

Tags: arrays, c, memory, struct

I have a byte array created like this in my C source file:

```
static char arr[64];
```

I also have a struct declared like so:

```
static char arr[64];

struct test {
    int foo;
    int data;
};
```

If everything in memory is just bytes, how could I store the bytes of of a `test` struct inside of `arr`

I have tried the following things:

```
int main() {
    struct test t;
    t.foo = 255;
    t.data = 364;

    arr[0] = t; // This did not work; I got a type-mismatch

    // I also tried memcpy

    memcpy(arr, &t, 8); // But this did not work either because it does not store the data in array. I was also not able to deference the bytes that did get stored.
}
```

Is there any easy way that I can store the bytes of the `test` struct in the byte array `arr` so that I can store multiple structures in this array and access it easily too?
If everything is just bytes, is there a feasible way to store the `test` struct bytes in the `arr` array?

Comment: You're getting into potential undefined behavior.  See [**What is the strict aliasing rule?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: @AndrewHenle I thought using `memcpy` was safe against aliasing and alignment requirements.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX The name of an array used in an expression or as a function parameter is automatically converted (decays) into a pointer to its first element.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX `arr` is declared globally (outside of main). So, it would be stored in global space.

Comment: `memcpy(arr, &t, 8);` or rather `memcpy(arr, &t, sizeof(struct test));` itself is fine, but what are you doing with `arr` later?

Comment: Using `sizeof(struct test)` instead of the `8` constant should work. Maybe an `int` is bigger than 4 bytes on your platform?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct test {
    int foo;
    int data;
};
int main() {
    struct test t;
    char arr[sizeof(struct test)];
    t.foo = 0x12345678;
    t.data = 1364;
    memcpy(arr, &t, sizeof(struct test));
    printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x\n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
    printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x\n", arr[4], arr[5], arr[6], arr[7]);
}
```

[This prints out](https://godbolt.org/z/99GvPY5oK)

```
78 56 34 12
54 05 00 00
```

(or thereabouts, depending on endianness and struct alignment).

Comment: Note that `struct test *t = (struct test *)arr;` **is** a strict-aliasing violation.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Revised with 100% more memcpy.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you are simply looking for this:
(assuming no struct padding ever present)

```
struct test {
  int foo;
  int data;
};

static struct test array [8] =
{
  { .foo = 123, .data = 456 }
  ...
};
```

Then for any random chunk of data of any type, C allows us to inspect it with a character pointer:

```
unsigned char* raw_data = (unsigned char*)&array;
...
raw_data[i] // access individual bytes
```

So the separate 64 byte array fills no purpose.

---

Alternatively, you *could* do this:

```
typedef struct {
  int32_t x;
  int32_t y;
} foo_t;

typedef union {
  foo_t   foo   [8];
  uint8_t bytes [64];
} bar_t;
```

Again, this is assuming no padding (a struct with just 2 int won't have any).